# How to wrap a functional component into a Layout component which is a higher order component?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router

I have my `Layout.js` as shown below:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Layout.module.scss';
export default function Layout(props) {
  const Component = props.renderComponent;
  return (
    <div className={classes.Layout}>
      <header></header>
      <main>
        <Component />
      </main>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And this is my `app.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import asyncComponent from './features/shared/hoc/asyncComponent/asyncComponent';
import Layout from './features/shared/hoc/Layout/Layout';
import LoginPage from './features/login-page/login';
const asyncConstruction = asyncComponent(() => {
  return import('./features/construction/construction');
});

function App(props) {
  let routes = (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path='/view' exact component={asyncConstruction} />
      <Redirect to='/' />
    </Switch>
  );

  if (props.isAuthenticated) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/checkout' component={asyncConstruction} />
        <Route path='/orders' component={asyncConstruction} />
        <Route path='/logout' component={asyncConstruction} />
        <Route path='/auth' component={asyncConstruction} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={asyncConstruction} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout renderComponent={routes} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

As you can see, I want to use `Layout.js` as a higher order component and pass my routes page so that they are rendered within the `<main>` of Layout.js. But when I try to do so, I get this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

How should I pass my props (which is actually a switch Route to my higher-order component `Layout.js`. My aim is to use `Layout.js` as a defined layout which contains headers and footers and all the components that I pass must be rendered in the main body of `Layout.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `childrens` like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className={"classes.Layout"}>
      <header></header>
      <main>{children}</main>
      <footer></footer>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const routes = (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/checkout" component={() => "hi"} />
        <Route path="/orders" component={() => "hi"} />
        <Route path="/logout" component={() => "hi"} />
        <Route path="/auth" component={() => "hi"} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={() => "hi"} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>{routes}</Layout>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you very much... This is exactly what I needed!